# Does $a \uparrow \uparrow (n+1)-a \uparrow \uparrow n$ divide $a \uparrow \uparrow(n+2) - a \uparrow \uparrow(n+1 )$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, tetration

Does

$$a\uparrow \uparrow (n+1) - a\uparrow \uparrow n$$

divide

$$a\uparrow \uparrow (n+2) - a\uparrow \uparrow (n+1)$$

for all $a,n \ge2$ ?

The case n = 0 is easy :

$$a^a-a=a(a^{a-1}-1)$$

and $a-1$ divides $a^{a-1}-1$

The case n = 1

$$a^{a^a}-a^a = a^a (a^{a^a-a}-1)=a^a(a^{a(a^{a-1}-1)}-1)$$

$$a^a-a = a(a^{a-1}-1)$$

and since $a-1$ divides $a^{a-1}-1$, the case is completed.

- Is my proof correct for the cases n=0 and n=1 ?
- Can this process be continued to enable an induction proof ?

Motivation :

A consequence of this divisibility would be :

If

$$a \uparrow \uparrow n \equiv a \uparrow \uparrow(n+1) \ mod\ (\ m\ ) $$

for some $a,n,m \ge2$ , then

$$a \uparrow \uparrow n \equiv a \uparrow \uparrow k \ mod\ (\ m\ ) $$

for all $k \ge n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Is my proof correct for the cases n=0 and n=1 ?

Yes, it is correct.

> - Can this process be continued to enable an induction proof ?

Sure. Let's write $T(a,n) = a \uparrow\uparrow n$. Then

$$\begin{align}
T(a,n+2) - T(a,n+1) &= a^{T(a,n+1)} - a^{T(a,n)}\\
&= a^{T(a,n)}\left(a^{T(a,n+1)-T(a,n)}-1\right).
\end{align}$$

The induction hypothesis gives $T(a,n+1) - T(a,n) = k\bigl(T(a,n) - T(a,n-1)\bigr)$, and monotonicity gives $T(a,n-1) \leqslant T(a,n)$, whence

$$\begin{align}
\frac{T(a,n+2)-T(a,n+1)}{T(a,n+1)-T(a,n)} &= \frac{a^{T(a,n)}\left(a^{T(a,n+1)-T(a,n)}-1\right)}{a^{T(a,n-1)} \bigl(a^{T(a,n)-T(a,n-1)}-1\bigr)}\\
&= a^{T(a,n) - T(a,n-1)}\cdot\frac{a^{k\bigl(T(a,n) - T(a,n-1)\bigr)}-1}{a^{T(a,n)-T(a,n-1)}-1}
\end{align}$$

is recognised as the product of two integers, hence an integer.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!